# How to properly call getInsertData and getDeleteData in main? Am I doing this part correct?

Tags: c++

I am working on a linked list assignment, however I am having trouble figuring out how to properly call `getInsertData()` (get values from `cin` and put them in a list) and `getDeleteData()` (delete numbers in the list)  in `main()`.

The instructions say something about defining an instance variable of `NumberList`, which I have already done I believe. If it's wrong, please correct me.

*(There is more to this assignment, but I'm just showing the part I am having an issue with)*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include "NumberList.h"

using namespace std;

NumberList *getInsertData(istream &, NumberList *);
NumberList *getDeleteData(istream &, NumberList *);

int main() {
    // Write your code here according to the instruction . . .
    int NumberList;
    // Assuming a getInsertData function goes here?
    cout << "Displaying list after inserting numbers" << endl;
    // getInsertData
    // Assuming a getDeleteData function goes here?
    cout << "Displaying list after deleting numbers" << endl;
    // getDeleteData 
    return 0;
}
```

My input is:

[image]

My intended output is supposed to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a variable named `NumberList` of type `int`.  You need to instead declare a variable of type `NumberList`.

Try something more like this:

```
int main() {
    NumberList myList;
    cout << "Displaying list after inserting numbers" << endl;
    getInsertData(cin, &myList);
    cout << "Displaying list after deleting numbers" << endl;
    getDeleteData(cin, &myList);
    return 0;
}
```